# How can we select mat option when press on tab key?, it should work like enter button in mat-autocomplete angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

How can we select mat option when press on tab key?, it should work like enter button in mat-autocomplete angular 6...
In below URL its working when press enter, but whenever we press tab button it should select highlighted option.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rdgjgqdggbg?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.ts)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can subscribe to this.autoTrigger.panelClosingActions, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hxbij?file=app%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.ts)

If your .html is like

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <!--see the reference variable-->
    <input #typehead type="text" ...>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
       ...
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

In your .ts

```
@ViewChild( 'typehead', {read:MatAutocompleteTrigger})  autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger; 

ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    this.autoTrigger.panelClosingActions.subscribe( x =>{
      if (this.autoTrigger.activeOption)
      {
        console.log(this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value)
        this.myControl.setValue(this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value)
      }
    } )
  }
```

**Update** a better aproach (using a directive) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156541/how-to-make-tab-key-as-enter-key-in-angular-material/55159386#55159386)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. the demo which you have sent is not working... the mat option is not selecting when press on tab key...

Comment: It work for me (in fireFox and Chrome), You need that some option is higligth (using arrow keys to select).

Comment: Filter is not implemented in the demo, so just use arrows to highlight, then tab to select. cheers.

Comment: This works automatically on the mat-select page on the 'Form field features' area and they obviously arent doing this. There must be a better way than a directive or subscribe