# How to make tab key as enter key in Angular Material?

Tags: html, angular, events, autocomplete, angular-material

this is my angular material auto complete code

```
<input type="search" id="setId" name="setId" [attr.list]='collectionType' [(ngModel)]="selValue" class="text-box"
  placeholder="--Select--" (focus)="ValidateParent()" (keyup.tab)="test()" (keyup)="EmitValues($event)" [id]="setId"
  [matAutocomplete]="auto" [title]="selValue" [placeholder]='WaterMarkText'>


<div [hidden]="IsCascading">
  <mat-autocomplete [id]="collectionType" #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)='onChange($event)'>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let items of codeList" [value]="items.text" [attr.data-text]='items.text' [id]="items.value">
      {{items.text}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</div>
```

Angular material had a problem with `tab` selection.like the material auto complete not able to select the value while click the `tab` button. but it's working while click the `enter` button. So manually I need to overwrite the `enter` key event on `tab` key event. How could possible?

Comment: You can use Angular CDK for this customization. A useful post: https://moduscreate.com/blog/adding-keyboard-navigation-to-angular-lists-using-angular-cdk-listkeymanager/

Comment: It's like select ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058305/how-can-we-select-mat-option-when-press-on-tab-key-it-should-work-like-enter-b/55059159#55059159

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Improve my comment, and based on the response we can create a directive

```js
import {
    Directive,
    AfterViewInit,
    OnDestroy,
    Optional
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    MatAutocompleteTrigger
} from '@angular/material';


@Directive({
    selector: '[tab-directive]'
})
export class TabDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    observable: any;
    constructor(@Optional() private autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger) {}
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.observable = this.autoTrigger.panelClosingActions.subscribe(x => {
            if (this.autoTrigger.activeOption) {
                this.autoTrigger.writeValue(this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value)
            }
        })
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.observable.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

You use:

```
<input tab-directive type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" 
      [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
```

(see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txehk4?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts))

**Update**  We can control only tab.key, else always you close, you get the selected value, so

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[tab-directive]'
})
export class TabDirective {
    observable: any;
    constructor(@Optional() private autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger) {}

    @HostListener('keydown.tab', ['$event.target']) onBlur() {
        if (this.autoTrigger.activeOption) {
            this.autoTrigger.writeValue(this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value)
        }
    }

}
```

[(see a new stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-txehk4-x3ycmq?file=app/tab-directive.ts)

**Update 2** I don't believe this answer has so many upvotes because it's wrong. As @Andrew allen comments, the directive not update the control. Well, It's late, but I try to solve. One Option is use

```
this.autoTrigger._onChange(this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value)
```

Anohter idea is inject the ngControl, so

```js
constructor(@Optional() private autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger,
    @Optional() private control: NgControl) {}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.observable = this.autoTrigger.panelClosingActions.subscribe(x => {
        if (this.autoTrigger.activeOption) {
            const value = this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value;
            if (this.control)
                this.control.control.setValue(value, {
                    emit: false
                });
            this.autoTrigger.writeValue(value);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: not all heros wear capes....I've referenced this answer for the discussion at https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4951 you are awesome my friend

Comment: @AndrewAllen, Thanks for refresh me, but thinking, I updated my answer to only get the value is you key down the tab key (else, escape key select the value too)

Comment: any way to cause input to revalidate or change invalid value of the input? Currently this shows my mat-error of "Required"

Comment: doing `this.autoTrigger._onChange(this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value);` as well as `writeValue` seems to fix validation aspects if you change your stackblitz to `myControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);`

Comment: @AndrewAllen, great your idea of use `this.autoTigger._OnChange`. I make another aproach -injecting the ngControl- . There are a little problem that is that we want that the obtions was a propertie of one object , e.g. `[value]="option.name"` because `writeValue` require the whole object, and, in this case `this.autoTrigger.activeOption` give us only the "name"

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party; so there's one annoying issue with  Eliseo's answer: It autocompletes even when the user has already selected a different option from the panel with a mouse click. The workaround I finally came up with was not straight forward at all.

```js
    /**
     * Selects currently active item on TAB
     * @example
     * <input vxTabActiveOption [matAutocomplete]="matAutocomplate">
     * <mat-autocomplete #matAutocomplate="matAutocomplete" autoActiveFirstOption>
     */
    @Directive({ selector: '[vxTabActiveOption]' })
    export class TabActiveOptionDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
      private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
    
      /**
       * Whether or not the autocomplete panel was open before the event
       */
      private panelOpen = false;
    
      constructor(
        private autoTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger,
        private control: NgControl
      ) { }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        const autocomplete = this.autoTrigger.autocomplete;
        merge(
          autocomplete.opened.pipe(map(() => true)),
          autocomplete.closed.pipe(map(() => false))
        ).pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroy$),
          delay(0)
        ).subscribe(value => this.panelOpen = value);
      }

      @HostListener('keydown.tab')
      onBlur() {
        if (this.panelOpen && this.autoTrigger.activeOption) {
          const value = this.autoTrigger.activeOption.value;
          this.control.control.setValue(value, { emit: false });
          this.autoTrigger.writeValue(value);
        }
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know it's an old question, but there're a better aproach that is use a directive like

```
@Directive({ selector: '[tab-selected]' })
export class TabSelected implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private auto: MatAutocomplete) {}
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.auto._keyManager.onKeydown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case TAB:
          if (this.auto.isOpen) {
            const option = this.auto.options.find(x => x.active);
            if (option) {
              option.select();
              event.preventDefault();
              return;
            }
          }
          this.auto._keyManager.tabOut.next();
          break;
        case DOWN_ARROW:
          this.auto._keyManager.setNextItemActive();
          break;

        case UP_ARROW:
          this.auto._keyManager.setPreviousItemActive();
          break;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

You use like

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
  <input type="text"
         placeholder="Pick one"
         aria-label="Number"
         matInput
         [formControl]="myControl"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete tab-selected #auto="matAutocomplete"
  autoActiveFirstOption >
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can be on work in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsmasc-4b3bhh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-tab.directive.ts)

Comment: Thanks - This work well but I found that if I then tab back in to the field and Angular re-opens the panel, you are stuck in the field.  Change "if (option)" to "if (option && !option.selected)" to fix that.  My preference is also that the tab key still advances to the next field so I removed the preventDefault() so allow that to happen.

Comment: I also didn't want a new option to be selected on backwards tabbing (Shift + Tab) so I modified the outer `if` to be `if (!event.shiftKey && this.auto.isOpen) {`

Also, `keyCode` is deprecated, so I used `code` and changed `TAB` to `'Tab'` and `DOWN_ARROW` to `'ArrowDown'` and `UP_ARROW` to `'ArrowUp`.